# $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be continuous bijection , $g \in C[0,1]$ and such that $\int_0^1g(x)(f(x))^{6n}dx=0, \forall n\ge 0$ , then $g=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be continuous bijection , $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous  such that

$\int_0^1g(x)(f(x))^{6n}dx=0, \forall n\ge 0$ , then is it true that $g(x)=0,\forall x \in [0,1]$ ?

I had done a problem where the condition were $\int_0^1g(x)x^ndx=0$ , but there the proof worked because by Weierstrass approximation theorem , the span of $\{1,x,x^2....\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ , for this problem I have no such idea . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the purpose of the $6$ in the exponent?

Comment: Do you know the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen To complicate the problem slightly, would be my guess. Of course, if $f$ is a contunious bijection, then $f^6$ will also be one.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Yes I see , as $f^6$ is continuous bijective , so the subspace spanned by the $f^{6n}$'s is a subalgebra , containing a non-zero constant function , which separates points ....

Comment: @Arthur : $f^6$ is bijective because fortunately range of $f$ is $[0,1]$

Comment: @user228169 Yes. If $f$ was a bijection with range $[0,2]$, say, then you would need to use $f^6/64$ to keep it a bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $f^6$ with $h$, and then consider the subalgebra of $C[0,1]$ generated by $h$. This separates points, thus is dense by Stone-Weierstrass. Now proceed as usual.